# Why are new columns added to parquet tables not available from glue pyspark ETL jobs?

Tags: pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

We've been exploring using Glue to transform some JSON data to parquet. One scenario we tried was adding a column to the parquet table. So partition 1 has columns [A] and partition 2 has columns [A,B]. Then we wanted to write further Glue ETL jobs to aggregate the parquet table but the new column was not available. Using `glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` to load the dynamic frame our new column was never in the schema.

We tried several configurations for our table crawler. Using a single schema for all partitions, single schema for s3 path, schema per partition. We could always see the new column in the Glue table data but it was always null if we queried it from a Glue job using pyspark. The column was in the parquet when we downloaded some samples and available for querying via Athena.

Why are the new columns not available to pyspark?

Answer (score 18):

This turned out to be a spark configuration issue. From [the spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging):

> Like Protocol Buffer, Avro, and Thrift, Parquet also supports schema evolution. Users can start with a simple schema, and gradually add more columns to the schema as needed. In this way, users may end up with multiple Parquet files with different but mutually compatible schemas. The Parquet data source is now able to automatically detect this case and merge schemas of all these files.
>
> Since schema merging is a relatively expensive operation, and is not a necessity in most cases, we turned it off by default starting from 1.5.0. You may enable it by
>
> 1. setting data source option mergeSchema to true when reading Parquet files (as shown in the examples below), or
> 2. setting the global SQL option spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema to true.

We could enable schema merging in two ways.

1. set the option on the spark session `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true")`
2. set `mergeSchema` to true in the `additional_options` when loading the dynamic frame.

```py
source = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
   database="db",
   table_name="table",
   additional_options={"mergeSchema": "true"}
)
```

After that the new column was available in the frame's schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should be in the dynamicframe docs

Comment: Up until now I had been delete the table's and letting it recreate - this was driving me nuts.  Adding in this additional option works!